# PHP AJAX not receiving SESSION

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, session

I have an image upload script which saves the file to the directory and a copy of the link to mySql.

If I put the user id as "123" it saves a new entry in the database. However, if I put the user id as $_SESSION['unique_user_id']; it does not put a new entry in the database but continues to save the file.

I've included `session_start();` on both the PHP pages but not the attached javascript file.

JS:

```
function doodleSave() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById("doodle-canvas");
    var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    $.post('test.php', {data: canvasData}, function (response) {

        var data = JSON.parse(response);

        if (data.filename !== false) {

            alert (data.filename);

        } else {

            alert('unable to upload');

        }
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
$unique_user_id = $_SESSION['unique_user_id'];


$randomFolder = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$upload_dir = "images/external/doodles/".$randomFolder."/";

if (!file_exists($upload_dir)) {
    mkdir($upload_dir, 0755, true);
}

$url            = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$unique_user_id = $_POST['userid'];
$unique_post_id = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$timestamp      = time();
$nature         = "doodle";
$imageUrl       = $upload_dir.$url.'.png';

$img = $_POST['data'];
$img = substr($img,strpos($img,",")+1);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir . $url . ".png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

if(!$success) {

    echo json_encode(['filename' => false]);
    exit(); // Prints success and exit the script

} else {

    require_once 'php/connect.php';

    try
    {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (unique_user_id, unique_post_id, nature, image_url, timestamp) VALUE (:unique_user_id, :unique_post_id, :nature, :image_url, :timestamp)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":unique_user_id",$unique_user_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(":unique_post_id",$unique_post_id);
        $stmt->bindParam(":nature",$nature);
        $stmt->bindParam(":image_url",$imageUrl);
        $stmt->bindParam(":timestamp",$timestamp);

        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            echo json_encode(['filename' => "in database"]);
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode(['filename' => "not in database"]);
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        $return_data = $e->getMessage();
    }
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: You're overwriting `$unique_user_id`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am so blind! Thank you for pointing that out. Works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in comments; you're overwriting `$unique_user_id`.

You started off by declaring it in:

```
$unique_user_id = $_SESSION['unique_user_id'];
```

Then overwrote it with:

```
$unique_user_id = $_POST['userid'];
```

You could also assign the POST array to the session array instead and check to see if it is set/not empty. This conditional check should be done in every page.